# How can I keep a value in a text input after a submit?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

Im writing this code in PHP and after i click Submit I want the values to be saved in the texbox.  first time when I open the page I see some errors inside textfild?How can i fix this ?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="GET">
First number<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['num1']  ; }?>"/>
Second number<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['num2'] ; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$num1=$_GET['num1'];
$num1=$_GET['num2'];
$sum=($num1+$num2);
echo "Sum is :<input type='text' value='$sum'/>";   
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the text of the errors plz. I'm guessing it has to do w/ a variable not being set.

Comment: this for one thing `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` will never fire up.

Comment: seems a peculiar mix of POST & GET.... how is this supposed to work when you use GET as the form method but do a logical test for POST?

Comment: Use sessions: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session

Answer (score 0):

When you first open the page, the GET variables are not yet set.

Do this instead:

```
First number<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="<?php echo (isset($_GET['num1']))? $_GET['num1'] : ""; ?>"/>
Second number<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="<?php echo (isset($_GET['num2']))? $_GET['num2'] : ""; ?>"/>
```

This will verify (using ternary expressions) if the get variable is set, if it is, then it will apply the value to the textbox.

Also, as mentioned below by mopo, this is a new feature in PHP7 that will also work, a simpler way.

```
First number<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['num1'] ?? ""; ?>"/>
Second number<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['num2'] ?? ""; ?>"/>
```

Also, you shouldn't check if the submit button is set using POST... it shouldn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ ...
}
```

You can verify if both `$_GET['num1']` and `$_GET['num2']` are set instead.

Comment: Super cool new feature in PHP7: `$_GET['num1'] ?? ''` http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: Yeah I heard about that one, Which is amazing, but I'm not sure which version OP is using :/

Comment: Sure thing. Not complaining about your answer, just adding to it.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a mention in the answer.

Comment: I used Post method like this and is Ok. THanks :)                                   First number<input type="text" name="num1"                                    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num1'])){echo $_POST['num1'] ;}  ?>"/>

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment. Are you changing the form method do 'post'?

Comment: yes i changed method to POST and code like above

Comment: Ok then, wherever I added $_GET to my answer, just change it to $_POST